# Third party Payment Integration

Tags: android, payment

I want to integrate a third party payment service in my app. Does Android stop me to doing so? is there any amount of money i have to give to google for using it?  Or are there any other terms & conditions??

Please help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, i don't think google will stop you. And i also dont think you need to give google anything.
For example check the android librarie from PayPal.. I've implemented it in a app and never had any trouble with it.

(BUT i didnt read any terms or conditions about this!!!)

**EDIT:**
agree with KrLx_roller

for mor information you can check :

http://www.android.com/us/developer-distribution-agreement.html

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to give any amount of money to Google. You are 100% free to add a third party payment service in your app.

But wait! You can do it provided you are not selling extra functions to your app, I mean, you can add a service to donate, but if your app is for downloading wallpapers (for example) you cannot give the option to buy extra wallpapers or add extra functions to the app...

Hope I've helped you!